# How does the code prints 1 2 6 24 as output and not 24 6 2 1

Tags: python

```
def recurr(k):  
       if (k>0):
           result =k*recurr(k-1)
           print(result)
       else:
           result=1
       return result 
recurr(4)
```

Output:

```
1
2
6
24
```

Comment: Because `recurr(4) --> 4*recurr(3*recurr(2*recurr(1*recurr(0))))`?

Comment: Then why does it print 1 2 6 24 in that order and not only 24

Comment: Because you have a `print` in your function.

Comment: Why does it print 1 2 6 24 and not 24 6 2 1

Comment: Have you stepped through this line by line? What part of understanding this specifically are you stuck on? Think though of what happens first, the recursive call, or the print?

Comment: Also, for such a small number of recursive calls, you can write out the execution path on some paper and see how and when the values are computed and displayed.

Comment: I am unable to understand the process of what's actually happens first.

Comment: You're not allowed to ask multiples of the same question here.  If you need further clarification, put comments on your first question.

Comment: @VedantBhosale, ...could you explain what part you still don't understand, even after reading the existing answers? Otherwise, it's not clear what a new answer could add that would help.

Comment: BTW, the [Python `trace` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) might be helpful to look at the order of operations in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're printing `result` *after* you recurse.

When you call `recurr(4)`, the first thing it does is call `recurr(3)`. This calls `recurr(2)`, then `recurr(1)`, and finally `recurr(0)`. This last one is the base case, so it returns `1`.

After that returns, you calculate `result = k * 1`, which is `result = 1 * 1`, then it prints that, so it prints `1` and then returns `1`.

Then the previous recursion calculates `result = k * 1`, which is `result = 2 * 1`, then it prints that, so it prints `2` and returns it.

This repeats through all the recursions.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you were printing result everytime you called it inside function instead of print what first call of function returned.

```
def recurr(k):  
    if (k>0):
        return k*recurr(k-1)
    return 1
print(recurr(4)) # -> 24
```

Comment: The result he's expecting is `24 6 2 1`, not just `24`

Answer (score 1):

Because in every call of the function recurr() the print() function is executed.
If you want to print 24 that's the code:

```
def recurr(k):
   if (k>0):
       result =k*recurr(k-1)
   else:
       result=1
   return result

print(recurr(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursion stack will print your message multiple times. This snippet may clarify why:

```
def factorial(k):
    if (k>0):
        print(f'factorial({k}) calls factorial({k-1})')
        result = k*factorial(k-1)
    else:
        print(f'factorial({k}) is the base case')
        result=1
    return result 

print(factorial(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the print part in your function. Instead, you should write the code like this at the end of the code:

print(recurr(4))

Comment: That will just print the final result, not all the numbers from each recursion.

Comment: I agree: Putting print into a function (a routine that returns a value) is an anti-pattern, but sometimes useful for tracing (learning what is happening).  the print should be in the calling procedure.

Comment: The question has been changed, i answered based on the original question in which he wanted to see only the final result.

Answer (score 0):

The point is, the function is calling itself, and each time the function is called and processes the "if" block, it throws out a print. as for the order, the function evaluates the brackets inside out. As stated by @timgeb in comments,

```
recurr(4) --> 4*recurr(3*recurr(2*recurr(1*recurr(0))))
```

This evaluates recurr(0), which then successfully evaluates recurr(1) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion in your code occurs on line 3, and the print statement occurs on line 4, after the recursion. When executing `recurr(4)`, the entire code for `recurr(3)` (including the print statement for `recurr(3)`) is executed before the print statement for `recurr(4)`.

Answer (score 0):

Get 4 friends. Label them 1!, 2!, 3! and 4!. Tell them that if asked what their value is they must ask (n-1)! for their value, and then multiply by n, write it on a bit of paper and hand to the asker. All asking, must also be done on a bit of paper.

Now ask 4! for their value, when you get it shout it out.

Next tell them to do the same but whenever they pass a bit of paper to someone, they mast also shout out the value. Record what happens.

Which of the shouters is the one to keep?

Answer (score 0):

When you use recursion, you build up a set of operation on the way down to the last call. Then you unroll them from the last, backwards up out to the first.

[image: stacking toy, with 10 at the bottom and 1 at the top]

In this toy, you build up your result from the highest number, by putting your operation (`k*next_value`) at the bottom, and build it up. Then you get the *result* of each operation, from the top to the bottom.